# Crontab running python script, Python script sleeping instead of exiting

Tags: python, linux, cron, python-venv

I am running a python script from a cron job in Amazon Linux. I activate the virtual environment first in cron. When I run "ps aux", it lists the process as sleeping.

```
myuser     12345  0.0  0.0    123    8 ?      Ss   Aug12   0:00 /bin/bash -c /usr/bin/python /home/myuser/my_script.py
```

I see "Ss" is the process state:

S Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)

s is a session leader

I put an exit command at the end of the script. It appears to be finishing, but in Linux it is sleeping.

I put a print statement at the last line that says "end", and I'm seeing that print.

Would anything about cronjobs or a virtual environment leave the process in a zombie state?

Comment: It would help if we could see your Python program (or at least a minimal version that reproduces the behavior you're asking about).

Comment: Turns out I left a connection open/ Thank you.